# Camel onException behvaing differently with rest and direct routes

Tags: apache-camel

I have a situation where `onException(TestException.class).maximumRedeliveries(3)` configured on a directrouteB in following image.

**Scenario(1)** When a request from a request comes from camel rest endpoint `/restA` which calls `directRouteA` and `directRouteA` calls `directRouteB` and while `directRouteB` processing if  `TestException` it is not retrying instead of retrying it is going to default error handler.

**Scenario(2)** when the request comes from camel rest endpoint `/restB` which calls `directRouteB` and while `directRouteB` processing if  `TestException` it is retrying 3 times as we mentioned.

Is that expected behavior or it should retry in both the cases.

[image]

Comment: is it possible for you to share a small code snippet on what you have tried?